# Автозагрузка сторонних классов

Tags: php, composer, namespace, autoload

Сам **__autoload**:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    $class  = @explode('\\', $class);
    $path = ROOT . implode('/', $class) . '.php';
    if( file_exists($path) ) require $path;
}
```

*Ни чего особенного*

Сегодня в проект решил подключить [PHP Html Parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser).
Все библиотеки я расположил в `App/Libraries`.
Данного пути нет в классах подключаемой библиотеки.
И получаю что то вроде:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   'App\Libraries\PHPHtmlParser\Dom' not found

Его конечно же можно дописать во все **namespace**, но это как то не тру.
Завтра будут другие библиотеки...

Решил попробовать так:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    $class  = @explode('\\', $class);
    $_aPath = implode('/', $class) . '.php';

    $path1 = ROOT . $_aPath;
    $path2 = ROOT . 'App/Helpers' . $_aPath;
    $path3 = ROOT . 'App/Libraries' . $_aPath;

    if( file_exists($path1) ) require $path1;
    else if( file_exists($path2) ) require $path2;
    else if( file_exists($path3) ) require $path3;
}
```

Все равно не нравится.

Можно как то во время **require** указать рутовый **namespace**?
Возможно есть какое то другое решение?
Или все все печально и таки придется дописывать?

**UPDATE**

---

Спасибо @Мелкий, переписал:

```
function autoloadClass($class)
{
    $class  = @explode('\\', $class);
    $path = ROOT . implode('/', $class) . '.php';
    if( file_exists($path) ) require $path;
}
spl_autoload_register('autoloadClass');
```

Прислушался к @etki и решили попробовать **composer**.

```
cd project
composer init && composer update
```

Было:

```
require_once ROOT.'Core/Autoload.php';
\Core\Database::$db = new \Core\Database(...);
```

Стало:

```
$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Core\\', __DIR__.'/Core/');
\Core\Database::$db = new \Core\Database(...);
```

И вот тут  я наверное не дочитал что то:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Core\Database' not found

По старому ессно работает.
Что делаю не так?

Comment: Поставьте composer и просто забудьте о всех этих сложностях

Comment: @etki, я пока не научился его готовить.

Comment: это займет меньше времени, чем решение вышеописанной проблемы

Comment: Ставьте composer. Во-первых, он для этого предназначен - управлять подключением внешних библиотек. Во-вторых, `__autoload` уже deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php

Comment: Читайте `PSR-0/4`

Comment: @etki, направьте на путь истинный, пожалуйста.

Comment: `composer require paquettg/php-html-parser` [Сам пакет](https://packagist.org/packages/paquettg/php-html-parser)

Comment: @vp_arth, я на работающий сайт не могу интегрировать composer. Про то что скинули, я знаю/видел, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант без **Composer**

У меня уже есть работающий проект на/по PSR-0.
Повторюсь, вот так подгружаются классы в проекте:

```
function autoloadClass($class)
{
    $class  = @explode('\\', $class);
    $path = ROOT . implode('/', $class) . '.php';
    if( file_exists($path) ) require $path;
}
spl_autoload_register('autoloadClass');
```

По [примеру автозагрузки PSR-4](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md) делаем скрипт для внешних библиотек.
Я сделал так:

```
namespace Core;

class AutoLoaderPSR4
{
    protected $prefixes = array();
    public function register(){ spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass')); }
    public function addNamespace($prefix, $base_dir, $prepend = false)
    {
        $prefix   = trim($prefix, '\\') . '\\';
        $base_dir = rtrim($base_dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . '/';
        if( isset($this->prefixes[$prefix]) === false ) $this->prefixes[$prefix] = array();
        if( $prepend ) array_unshift($this->prefixes[$prefix], $base_dir);
        else array_push($this->prefixes[$prefix], $base_dir);
    }
    public function loadClass($class)
    {
        $prefix = $class;
        while( false !== $pos = strrpos($prefix, '\\') )
        {
            $prefix         = substr($class, 0, $pos + 1);
            $relative_class = substr($class, $pos + 1);
            $mapped_file    = $this->loadMappedFile($prefix, $relative_class);
            if( $mapped_file ) return $mapped_file;
            $prefix = rtrim($prefix, '\\');
        }
        return false;
    }
    protected function loadMappedFile($prefix, $relative_class)
    {
        if( isset($this->prefixes[$prefix]) === false ) return false;
        foreach( $this->prefixes[$prefix] as $base_dir )
        {
            $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';
            if( $this->requireFile($file) ) return $file;
        }
        return false;
    }
    protected function requireFile($file)
    {
        if( file_exists($file) )
        {
            require $file;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Далее в нужном месте *(на примере того же PHPHtmlParser)* :

```
$loader = new \Core\AutoLoaderPSR4();
$loader->addNamespace('PHPHtmlParser', ROOT.'App/Libraries/PHPHtmlParser');
$loader->addNamespace('stringEncode', ROOT.'App/Libraries/stringEncode');
$loader->register();

$dom = new \PHPHtmlParser\Dom();
$dom->load($strHTML);
```

Пока полет нормальный.
Надеюсь кому-то пригодится.

Answer (score 1):

Изобретаете велосипед. Стандартными методами самого `composer` можно решить подгрузку классов намного проще. Например, у вас есть проект с такой структурой:

```
├── apps
│   ├── config
│   │   ...
│   └── controllers
│       ├── api
│       │    └── ContactsController.php
│       └── web
│            └── WebController.php
├── library
│   ...
├── views
│   ...
├── public
│   └── index.php
├── vendor
│   ├── autoload.php
│   ...
├── composer.json
└── composer.lock
```

Тогда вам достаточно поправить свой `composer.json` следующим образом, чтобы подгружать классы, в соответствующих папках и пространствах имен:

```
{
  ...
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "YourApp\\Controllers\\Web\\": "apps/controllers/web",
      "YourApp\\Controllers\\API\\": "apps/controllers/api"
    }
  }
}
```

После этого вы можете спокойно использовать эти классы, через `use YourApp\Controllers\Web\ContactsController`, например.